# Хочу узнать на чем написан сайт

Tags: веб-программирование, frontend

Хочу узнать, на чем написан сайт и как научиться писать такие же сайты.
Сам сайт: http://www.benmingo.com/

Comment: Любой фреймворк под JS (Vue, React), Библиотека [GSAP](https://greensock.com/) для анимацией всего, [GLSL](https://shadertoy.com/) для создания шейдеров.

Comment: вам интересно, как написан код или на какой CMS сделан конкретный сайт?

Comment: @МаксЖуков там не CMS

Comment: какая наркоманская фантазия а не ui

Answer (score 1):

этот сайт написан на **JS**(на фреймворке под него)

Comment: И на каком же фреймвёрке?